# How to suppress entire section of main report when subreport is blank

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have the report designed with following sections.

```
Report Header
```

> I have added few fields to display report title and other header
>   information followed by a sub report. I hide/show this section with a
>   parameter value and it is working just perfect.

```
Page Header a
```

I have the header information here.

```
Page Header b
```

I have report title here. Hide/Show this section based on the parameter value

```
Page Header c
```

Fields header goes here

```
Group Header #1
```

Suppressed

```
Details
```

Detailed fields

```
Group Footer #1
```

Suppressed

```
Report Footer a
```

Blank and suppressed

```
Report Footer b
```

I have added few fields to display report title and other header information followed by a sub report.

```
Page Footer
```

Blank

I need a way to suppress Page Header a, Page Header b and Page Header c when I’m printing Report Footer b. Because it has its own header. I also need to suppress the entire section of Report Footer b when the sub report is blank. Any suggestion/help greatly appreciated.

Comment: the content of your subreport is from a query? or from where?

Comment: I have used field definition file during design. During run-time data is getting added through CrystalDataObject.CrystalComObject.AddRows from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a solution from within the code. If the data rows for the crystal object is empty then

```
CRAXDRT.Report.Sections("RFb").Suppress = True
```

This solution worked for me. To suppress the main report header for the subreport section when the subreport contains data, placed a formula in the Report footer a

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global booleanvar no_header := True;
```

In the section expert set the suppress formula as

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global booleanvar no_header;
no_header
```

for Page Header a, Page Header b and Page Header c
Thank you all for your time to respond. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In crystal report, you can do it via setting.

To suppress blank sections:

1. Go to Report > Section Expert
2. Highlight the section that is showing blanks (in this example, the
   Details section)
3. Mark the Suppress Blank Section checkbox
4. Click OK

https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/75439

even for subreport , if you right click on subreport, set "Suppress when blank"

[Suppressing subreport with no data and a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499919/suppressing-subreport-with-no-data-and-a-header)

Comment: I have the subreport in the Report Footer b. I have some fields along with the subreport in this section. I need to supress this entire section, if the subreport is blank or empty

Comment: check the second link