# Suppres subreport in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building a PDF document from CrystalReport.
My Report have more SubReport (in section). I want to hide the section that not have any result.
So my subreport have a table23. If the table23 is empty, I want to suppres this section.

For this I have right-click on Header of section. Section Expert, click on Suppres empty section.
In the formula I have write this formula:

```
If Count({Table23.Data})>0  Then
False //Non omette
Else
True //Omette
```

[image]

But after that, if I try to start my report I can see the detail section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppressing subreport with no data and a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499919/suppressing-subreport-with-no-data-and-a-header)

Answer (score 0):

The Formula is unnecessary... A check mark "Suppres empty section" is enough.
But you have to suppress the empty subreport. Right-click on Subreport -> Format Subreport -> Subreport tab -> "suppress empty subreport".